# Windows script to install multiple Android apps

Tags: android, windows, scripting

In my Android Studio project I have some different apps and I want to build and install all of them at once. I didn't know if there is any way to do it without the terminal but with the terminal what I do is the following:

```
gradlew.bat assembleDebug
```

To build all the apps, and after:

```
adb -d install app1.apk
```

To install app1 in my device. If I do:

```
adb -d install app1.apk | adb -d install app2.apk
```

I will install app1 and app2 (app1.apk have the whole path of the apk location). So I want to build a script who have the four command for install my four apps but I don't know what to do on windows to do that. I think I can't just create my_script.sh like this:

```
adb -d install app1.apk 
adb -d install app2.apk
adb -d install app3.apk
adb -d install app4.apk
```

and execute it... so I need your help. How can I do a command script like that on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally I found an answer. Scripts on windows are made it as in Linux but instead .sh there are .bat. Actually I found a better way to do what I want to do on Gradle instead of I was trying to do I use the install task of gradle called like this:

```
gradlew :app1:installRelease :app2:installRelease :app3:installRelease :app4:installRelease
```

Even you only need to put the fewer character needed to differenciate tasks. For example if you have Release and Debug build variants you only need to write:

```
gradlew :app1:iR
```

To execute the installRelease of app1 in gradle.